# C - Populate matrix with some density

Tags: c, matrix, initialization

I've got this code to populate matrix with 0/1 values and RHO density. I need the same for values from 0 to 2. I mean, the percentage of zeros should be the same, but other values in range 1-2.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        grid[cur][i][j] = (((float)rand())/RAND_MAX) < rho;
    }
}
```

The only thing I've been able to do is something inelegant like this. This leaves zero/non zero percentage inalterate and random modifies the 1 cells:

```
...
if(grid[cur][i][j] > 0) {
    grid[cur][i][j] += rand()%2;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you want this reviewed?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for better code? Are you looking for code that changes the location of `0` but maintain the overall count of `0` (and alters `1` to either `1` or `2`)?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I was looking for a reviewed version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code will create 0 with RHO density and other values in range 1-2.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        grid[cur][i][j] = (((float)rand())/RAND_MAX) < rho ? 0 : rand() % 2 + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I set rho = 0.1 this code ppulate matrix with high percentage of non-zero values, with 0.9 with minor percentage, that is the opposite i want. So just need to change versus in `> rho` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: But note that for many `rand()` implementations, `rand() % 2` is not so random. Fine for a game, maybe, but for any simulation where you care about the results, not fine.